# Prevent user redirect to login page if not logged in / Symfony3 FosUserBndl

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

I'm using [Symfony3](http://symfony.com/) for a web application with the [FosUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) for user management.

I inserted in my app the login and register form as followed in my header.html.twig. This file (header) is inserted in my main file (base.html.twig) which means that it is inserted on almost all my pages.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" role="dialog">
        {{ render(controller('UserBundle:Registration:Register', {'request': app.request})) }}
  </div> 

  <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
        {{ render(controller('UserBundle:Security:Login')) }}
  </div>
```

The problem is that when I try to access the home page http://localhost/baseurl/web/app_dev.php/ I am redirected to http://localhost/baseurl/web/app_dev.php/login `fos_user_security_login` (the FosUserBundle login route configured in the login_path of the security.yml.) 
I don't understand how to configure and use the FUB in the case I have overrided and inserted the security_login form in the header

My security.yml is as followed :

```
security:

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: /
                failure_path: /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SECRETAIRE: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_SECRETAIRE]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_SECRETAIRE }
```

config.yml :

```
# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver:              orm
    firewall_name:          main
    user_class:             UserBundle\Entity\User
    use_listener:           true
    use_flash_notifications: true
    use_authentication_listener: true
    use_username_form_type: true
    model_manager_name:     null  # change it to the name of your entity/document manager if you don't want to use the default one.
    from_email:
        address:        xxx@gmail.com
        sender_name:    Gauthier
    profile:
        form:
            type:               FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
    change_password:
        form:
            type:               FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ChangePasswordFormType
            name:               fos_user_change_password_form
            validation_groups:  [ChangePassword, Default]
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    false
            template:   '@FOSUser/Registration/email.txt.twig'
        form:
            type:               UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType
            name:               fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 86400
        email:
            template:   '@FOSUser/Resetting/email.txt.twig'
        form:
            type:               FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ResettingFormType
            name:               fos_user_resetting_form
            validation_groups:  [ResetPassword, Default]
    service:
        mailer:                 fos_user.mailer.default
        email_canonicalizer:    fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
        username_canonicalizer: fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
        token_generator:        fos_user.util.token_generator.default
        user_manager:           fos_user.user_manager.default
```

When I add a `die('ok');` in my controller matched with the route 'homepage' (http://localhost/baseurl/web/app_dev.php/), I'm not redirected to `/login` but I have "ok" print on a white page. I don't understand where the redirection to /login is done

Comment: You can configure on form_login from security.yml, see like this : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/849.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the same problem. My problem is that I'm redirected to /login if not loggedin, but thanks anyway for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FOSUserBundle docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

> Next, take a look at and examine the firewalls section. Here we have declared a firewall named main. By specifying form_login, you have told the Symfony Framework that **any time a request is made to this firewall** that leads to the user needing to authenticate himself, **the user will be redirected to a form where he will be able to enter his credentials**.

To allow accesss to your homepage you could add something like this:

```
# app/config/security.yml file
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        # allow anonymous access to the homepage:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

In this case, the pattern for the index action in `routing.yml` has to be "/".